# Handlebars: pass increment to partial for all elements on same level?

Tags: handlebars.js

I'm trying to render a nested ul structure using a recursive strategy. I'm facing the problem of passing and increment value to the partial so that I can set a unique class name for each level (which have multiple elements).

@index will not work as it will give each item a different value on the same level. I need all elements on the same level to have the same value, only incremented on each nesting, as in:

pseudo-code

```
level_element class="indent_1"
level_element class="indent_1"
level_element class="indent_1"
level_element class="indent_1"
    level_element class="indent_2"
    level_element class="indent_2"
    level_element class="indent_2"
    level_element class="indent_2"
        level_element class="indent_3"
        level_element class="indent_3"
        level_element class="indent_3"
        level_element class="indent_3"
```

etc.

I'm doing this (well trying to) pseudo-code
:

```
{{#each this}}
    element_with_class_indent_{{INITIAL_INCREMENT_VALUE}}
    {{#if sub_level}}
        {{> level indent=INITIAL_INCREMENT_VALUE + 1}} // Pass value to all elements on next level
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this by creating a [helper](http://handlebarsjs.com/#helpers) to increment an integer. I would design my partial view so that it could recursively call itself, passing the `indent` as a [parameter](http://handlebarsjs.com/partials.html#partial-parameters). I would use a [subexpression](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html#subexpressions) to increment the value of `indent` (using my helper) at each nested level.

The increment helper would be *very* simple:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('increment', function (value) {
    return value + 1;
});
```

Assuming a recursive data structure with an array of Items, each with a `title` and an array of Items, `children`, the partial view, "menu", would look something like the following:

```
<ul>
    {{#each items}}
        <li class="indent_{{../indent}}">
            {{title}}
            {{#if children}}
                {{> menu items=children indent=(increment ../indent)}}
            {{/if}}
        </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

To render the menu, the template would call the partial, passing `1` as the initial `indent` value:

```
{{> menu items=this indent=1}}
```

I have created an example fiddle that you can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/k1qu3mqd/).