# Indentation for recursive handlebars templates

Tags: handlebars.js

When using Handlebars templates to generate output, proper indentation is important to make the output readable. I can not get the correct indentation to display a nested data structure, such as a JSON object.

Suppose you have a JSON object like this:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "name": "one",
  "children": [
    {
      "type": "object",
      "name": "two",
      "children": [
        {
          "type": "scalar",
          "name": "three",
          "value": "3"
        },
        {
          "type": "object",
          "name": "Deep",
          "children": [
            {
              "type": "scalar",
              "name": "four",
              "value": "4"
            },
            {
              "type": "scalar",
              "name": "five",
              "value": "5"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And you want to generate output using the following Handlebars template:

```
{{!
       ========================= object ===============================
}}
{{#*inline "object"}}
{{name}}: {
{{#each children}}
        {{> "json"}}{{#unless @last}},{{/unless}}
{{/each}}
    }{{/inline}}
{{!
       ========================= scalar ===============================
}}
{{#*inline "scalar"}}
{{name}}: {{value ~}}
{{/inline}}
{{!
       ========================= json ===============================
}}
{{#*inline "json"}}
{{#switch type}}
{{#case 'object'}}{{> "object"}}{{/case ~}}
{{#case 'scalar'}}{{> "scalar"}}{{/case ~}}
{{/switch}}
{{/inline}}
{{!
       ========================= main =================================
}}
{{> "json" this}}
```

The output you get is:

```
one: {
        two: {
        three: 3,
        Deep: {
        four: 4,
        five: 5
    }
    }
    }
```

Note the lack of proper indentation. How can I resolve the problem and have the output formatted correctly?

PS. I got used to the [StringTemplate](https://www.stringtemplate.org/) library where you have the proper indentation without any additional effort. Is it possible to get the same result from Hanbdlebars without resolving to other helpers, explicit indent evaluations, and so on, as I found in some older posts?

- [Explicit solution with additional helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907643/handlebars-pass-increment-to-partial-for-all-elements-on-same-level)

PS. JSON is used to illustrate the problem with the recursive templates, I **do not** need to print JSON objects.

Comment: What is the use-case for the output? If you are creating a file, I would use a formatting tool, like [Prettier](https://prettier.io/docs/en/cli.html), to format the output of the Handlebars template.

Comment: Generation of JavaScript code from an internal structure

Comment: If you are generating JavaScript files then I think Prettier would be a good tool. Here is an example of a script that uses Handlebars and Pettier to create a JSON file: https://github.com/76484/so-75502122/blob/main/index.js